# CSS relative and absolute, ignoring z-index

Tags: html, css

I have a grid of **li**'s all floated left with a fixed width/height. The problem is when I hover over the Latest Product in the centre, the div which is displayed in not positioned on top and sits under the next **li's**

EDIT/BREAKTHROUGH:
If I remove the z-index on the relative `li` this works in all browsers except IE7

Comment: Look for some IE7 specifics on z-index. But if t works in all major borwsers, IE7 users can afford to suffer (They should have upgraded years ago anyway)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the hovered LI's z-index to make it greater than it's siblings, like so in your productOver function:

```
function productOver(){
  var product_html = $(this).find(".product_html");
  // Generate HTML only on first hover.
  if(product_html.data("generated") != true){
    var tis = $(this);
    product_html.find(".name").html(tis.find("h2").html());
    product_html.find(".price").html(tis.find(".price").html());
    product_html.data("generated", true);
  }
  $(this).css('z-index','10'); //add this
  product_html.stop().fadeTo('fast', 1).show();
}
```

and of course set it back to it's default on productOut

```
function productOut(){ 
  $(this).css('z-index', '8'); //add this
  $(this).find(".product_html").stop().fadeTo('slow', 0, function() {
    $(this).hide(); 
  });
}
```

Comment: I was over complicating it in my head, this worked brill thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put `z-index: 1;` to the bottom row LIs and higher z-inded to all the elements that appear on hover. That should get you started.

Comment: Each of the `LI` already has a z-index:8, the element that appears on hover has z-index:999

Comment: I know, but giving them z-index: 1 fixed it for me.